# For which $n$ is there $B$ that satisfies $B^n=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am given matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

I am then supposed to find $n \ge 2$ such that there is a $B \in M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $B^n = A$.

I first tried to show this by trying to find the eigenvalues of A and diagonalize it, but as we can see this matrix has a single eigenvalue of $0$ and is not diagonalizable.

I was wondering if there is a different way to try to show this. If you could let me know, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $B$ can be a Jordan block...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using (directed) graphs.  Take $A$ and $B$ to be adjacency matrices of $G_A,G_B$ respectively.  The relation that $B^n=A$ means that $a_{ij}$ is the number of walks of length $n$ in graph $G_B$ from $i$ to $j$.

We want a graph such that there is exactly one walk of length $n$ from the first to fourth node, and no other walks of length $n$ anywhere in the graph.  If $G_B$ is a path graph with the first node connected to the second, second to the third, and third to the fourth, then there is only one walk of length $3$ and it takes the first node to the fourth as desired.  The adjacency matrix of this graph is

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$